# XMl Serialize and Deserialize Multiple derived Classes in C#

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I tried following the Microsoft website documentation for addressing the above question. However, I'm not able to find the answer. So I tried writing the code, but my object is not getting serialized when I added more derived classes.

Here goes the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Orchestra
{
    // public Instrument[] Instruments;
    public List<Instrument> Instruments;
    public int i;
    public float f;
    public string s1;
    public string s2;
    public B bc;
}
public class B
{
    public double dd;
}
public class Instrument
{
    public string Name;
}

public class Brass : Instrument
{
    public bool IsValved;
}
public class Percussion : Instrument
{
    public string name;
}
public class Run
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Run test = new Run();
        test.SerializeObject("Override.xml");
        test.DeserializeObject("Override.xml");
    }

    public void SerializeObject(string filename)
    {
        /* Each overridden field, property, or type requires 
        an XmlAttributes object. */
        XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();

        /* Create an XmlElementAttribute to override the 
        field that returns Instrument objects. The overridden field
        returns Brass objects instead. */
        XmlElementAttribute attr = new XmlElementAttribute();
        attr.ElementName = "Brass";
        attr.Type = typeof(Brass);

        attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);
      //  attrs.XmlArrayItems.Add(attr);

       attr.ElementName = "Percussion";
        attr.Type = typeof(Percussion);
        // Add the element to the collection of elements.
        attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);

        // Create the XmlAttributeOverrides object.
        XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

        /* Add the type of the class that contains the overridden 
        member and the XmlAttributes to override it with to the 
        XmlAttributeOverrides object. */
        attrOverrides.Add(typeof(Orchestra), "Instruments", attrs);

        // Create the XmlSerializer using the XmlAttributeOverrides.
        XmlSerializer s =
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(Orchestra), attrOverrides);

        // Writing the file requires a TextWriter.
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);

        // Create the object that will be serialized.
        Orchestra band = new Orchestra();

        // Create an object of the derived type.
        //Brass i = new Brass();
        //i.Name = "Trumpet";
        //i.IsValved = true;
        //Instrument[] myInstruments = { i };
        //band.Instruments = myInstruments;
        List<Instrument> myInstruments = new List<Instrument>();
        myInstruments.Add(new Brass() { Name = "Trumpet", IsValved = true });
        myInstruments.Add(new Percussion() { Name = "Percussion", name = "Mridangam" });
        band.Instruments = myInstruments;
        band.i = 128;
        band.f = 5.678f;
        band.s1 = "Hi!";
        band.s2 = "GOOD!!!";
        B b = new B();
        b.dd = 2.35674848;
        band.bc = b;
        // Serialize the object.
        s.Serialize(writer, band);
        writer.Close();
    }

    public void DeserializeObject(string filename)
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides =
           new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();

        // Create an XmlElementAttribute to override the Instrument.
        XmlElementAttribute attr = new XmlElementAttribute();
        attr.ElementName = "Brass";
        attr.Type = typeof(Brass);

        // Add the element to the collection of elements.
        attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);

        attrOverrides.Add(typeof(Orchestra), "Instruments", attrs);

        // Create the XmlSerializer using the XmlAttributeOverrides.
        XmlSerializer s =
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(Orchestra), attrOverrides);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        Orchestra band = (Orchestra)s.Deserialize(fs);
        Console.WriteLine(band.i);
        Console.WriteLine(band.f);
        Console.WriteLine(band.s1);
        Console.WriteLine(band.s2);
        Console.WriteLine(band.bc.dd);
        Console.WriteLine("Brass:");

        /* The difference between deserializing the overridden 
        XML document and serializing it is this: To read the derived 
        object values, you must declare an object of the derived type 
        (Brass), and cast the Instrument instance to it. */
        //Brass b;
        //Percussion p;
        Brass b;
       // Percussion p;
        //b = (Brass)i;
       // int ii = 0;
        foreach (Instrument i in band.Instruments)
        //foreach(Instrument i in band.List<Instrument>)
        {
            //        int i = 0;
         //   ii++;
          //  if (ii == 1)
         //   {
                b = (Brass)i;
                Console.WriteLine(
                    b.Name + "\n" +
                    b.IsValved);
           // }
            /*if (ii == 2)
            {
                p = (Percussion)i;
                Console.WriteLine(
                    p.Name + "\n" +
                    p.name);

            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

I even tried using `XmlArrayItem`. Could anyone guide how to go about this?

Comment: Have you tried "[Serializable]" before the class Declare?

Comment: @VinhCC The `[Serializable]` attribute is **not** related to XML serialization.

Comment: *"is not getting serialized* — so what error message are you getting? What does the serialized XML look like? Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Specify the exact problem! Your code doesn't compile? Compiles but does not start? Starts but crashes with an exception? It works out to the end, but gives the wrong result?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new class Instruments to your code. See code below :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

public class Orchestras
{
    public List<Orchestra> orchestras = new List<Orchestra>();
}
public class Orchestra
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Instrument> Instruments { get; set; }
    public int i;
    public float f;
    public string s1;
    public string s2;
    public B bc;
}
public class B
{
    public double dd;
}
[XmlInclude(typeof(Brass))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Percussion))]
public class Instrument
{
    public string Name;
}

public class Brass : Instrument
{
    public bool IsValved;
}
public class Percussion : Instrument
{
    public string name;
}
public class Run
{
    const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
    public static void Main()
    {
        Run test = new Run();
        test.SerializeObject(FILENAME);
        test.DeserializeObject(FILENAME);
    }

    public void SerializeObject(string filename)
    {
        Orchestras orchastras = new Orchestras();
        Orchestra orchestra1 = new Orchestra();
        orchastras.orchestras.Add(orchestra1);
        List<Instrument> instruments = new List<Instrument>() { 
            new Instrument() { Name = "Brass"},
            new Instrument() { Name = "Percussion"}
        };

        orchestra1.Instruments = instruments;


        // Create the XmlSerializer using the XmlAttributeOverrides.
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Orchestras));


        // Writing the file requires a TextWriter.
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename,settings);

        // Create the object that will be serialized.
        Orchestra band = new Orchestra();
        orchastras.orchestras.Add(band);
        // Create an object of the derived type.
        //Brass i = new Brass();
        //i.Name = "Trumpet";
        //i.IsValved = true;
        //Instrument[] myInstruments = { i };
        //band.Instruments = myInstruments;
        List<Instrument> myInstruments = new List<Instrument>();
        myInstruments.Add(new Brass() { Name = "Trumpet", IsValved = true });
        myInstruments.Add(new Percussion() { Name = "Percussion", name = "Mridangam" });
        band.Instruments = myInstruments;
        band.i = 128;
        band.f = 5.678f;
        band.s1 = "Hi!";
        band.s2 = "GOOD!!!";
        B b = new B();
        b.dd = 2.35674848;
        band.bc = b;
        // Serialize the object.
        s.Serialize(writer, orchastras);
        writer.Close();
    }

    public void DeserializeObject(string filename)
    {

        // Create the XmlSerializer using the XmlAttributeOverrides.
        XmlSerializer s =
           new XmlSerializer(typeof(Orchestras));

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        Orchestras band = (Orchestras)s.Deserialize(fs);
        Console.WriteLine(band.orchestras[1].i);
        Console.WriteLine(band.orchestras[1].f);
        Console.WriteLine(band.orchestras[1].s1);
        Console.WriteLine(band.orchestras[1].s2);
        Console.WriteLine(band.orchestras[1].bc.dd);
        Console.WriteLine("Brass:");

        /* The difference between deserializing the overridden 
        XML document and serializing it is this: To read the derived 
        object values, you must declare an object of the derived type 
        (Brass), and cast the Instrument instance to it. */
        //Brass b;
        //Percussion p;
        Instrument b;
        // Percussion p;
        //b = (Brass)i;
        // int ii = 0;
        foreach (Instrument i in band.orchestras[1].Instruments)
        //foreach(Instrument i in band.List<Instrument>)
        {
            //        int i = 0;
            //   ii++;
            //  if (ii == 1)
            //   {
            b = i;
            Console.WriteLine(
                b.Name + "\n");

            // }
            /*if (ii == 2)
            {
                p = (Percussion)i;
                Console.WriteLine(
                    p.Name + "\n" +
                    p.name);

            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could You please explain me the code that you have written, I am unable to understand the code you have written

Comment: The code is the same as you posted except I added a new class Orchestras and put two orchestras into the class.  I also used a XmlWriter instead of your StreamWriter.  I also had to add XmlInclude because you have two classes that inherit the same base class.

Comment: How to serialize the same code if all the member variables are private? Can i still use XmIInclude,Typeof, XmlElement, and instantiate an object of DataContract Serializer() instead of XMlSerializer?

Comment: I've never tried it.  I think it should work , but you should try it yourself.

Comment: ok thanks jdweng. i will try it and come back